# Sinatra show view /example/:id returns 404 error for assets, when using sprockets

Tags: ruby, sinatra, assets, sprockets

When I am accessing:

```
get "/example/:id" do
  ...
  slim :'example/show'
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
"GET /example/assets/app.css HTTP/1.1" 404
"GET /example/assets/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404
```

---

I am suspecting that `:id` can be a problem here, because 
my assets setup works when I am accessing:

```
get "/example" do
  ...
  slim :'example/index'
end
```

works:

```
"GET /assets/app.css HTTP/1.1" 304
"GET /assets/app.js HTTP/1.1" 200
```

My setup for sprockets:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
  set :environment, Sprockets::Environment.new

  environment.append_path "assets/stylesheets"
  environment.append_path "assets/javascripts"

  environment.js_compressor  = :uglify
  environment.css_compressor = :scss

  get "/assets/*" do
    env["PATH_INFO"].sub!("/assets", "")
    settings.environment.call(env)
  end

  ...

end
```

My full repo but without last changes: https://github.com/aneta-bielska/home-for-paws-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout you have the following lines which define the links to your assets:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/app.css"
script src="assets/app.js"
```

Since the urls in these elements don’t start with a slash, the browser treats them as relative to the page where they appear. This means that when you visit `/example` the links go to `/assets/app.cs` and `/assets/app.js`. However when you go to e.g `example/1` the links are treated as relative to the `1`, so the browser tries to fetch `/example/assets/app.cs` (and similarly for `app.js`).

You need to make sure theses links are always treated as absolute. The simplest way would be to just add a `/` at the start:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/app.css"
script src="/assets/app.js"
```

A more robust solution might be to use [Sinatra’s `url` helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Generating%20URLs) to ensure you always create the correct links, as it will take it account mounting the app at different paths on the server:

```
link rel="stylesheet" href=url("/assets/app.css")
script src=url("/assets/app.js")
```

Comment: Looks like that's all I needed. Thank you!